# How do I iterate over JSON array that is converted from XML?

Tags: node.js, xml, express, async-await, axios

I have a function that calls another function to get data from axios. I am not able to iterate over the array of the json object. It shows as undefined, I am not sure why?

The final function:

```
async function final(){
    let final = []
    let data1 = await getPeople();
    let data2 = await getXml();
    for(i=0;i<data1.length;i++){
        final.push(data1[i]);
    }
    console.log(data2.persons.person)
    for(j=0;j<data2.persons.person.length;j++){
        final.push(data2[j])
    }
    final.sort();
    return final;
}
```

Get xml function:

```
async function getXml(){
let ans;
const {data} = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SwayamShah97/a3619c5828ac8ed8085c4ae295a855d9/raw/e4e372552e042bd8bd9e8ab87da93eb030114f86/people.xml');
xml2js.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }

    const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);

    ans = json
    
});
return ans;

}
```

I am getting the data correctly from the xml function but how do I iterate over person?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your code. First, you do not want to stringify the result of the xml2js parsing. You want to keep it a JavaScript object.

Second, you don't iterate over the correct node in your results. You log it correctly, but then you iterate over a parent node. This is a minimal fix to your code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import xml2js from 'xml2js';

async function getXml() {
  let ans;
  const { data } = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SwayamShah97/a3619c5828ac8ed8085c4ae295a855d9/raw/e4e372552e042bd8bd9e8ab87da93eb030114f86/people.xml');
  xml2js.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    // const json = JSON.stringify(result, null, 4);

    ans = result;
  });
  return ans;
}

async function final() {
  const final = [];
  // const data1 = await getPeople();
  const data2 = await getXml();
  // for (let i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
  //   final.push(data1[i]);
  // }
  console.log(data2.persons.person);
  for (let j = 0; j < data2.persons.person.length; j += 1) {
    final.push(data2.persons.person[j]);
  }
  final.sort();
  return final;
}

console.log(await final());
```

There are other things that could be cleaned up, but this will get you going.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this transformation with camaro like this. it will be simpler

```js
const { transform } = require('camaro')

async function main() {
    const xml = `
<persons>
   <person>
       <id>3</id>
       <firstName>Jen</firstName>
       <lastName>Doe</lastName>
   </person>
   <person>
       <id>6</id>
       <firstName>Stephanie</firstName>
       <lastName>Joe</lastName>
   </person>
   <person>
       <id>1</id>
       <firstName>Victoria</firstName>
       <lastName>Doe</lastName>
   </person>
</persons>
`

    const template = {
        persons: ['persons/person', {
            id: 'id',
            firstName: 'firstName',
            lastName: 'lastName'
        }]
    }
    const { persons } = await transform(xml, template)
    console.log(persons);
}

main()
```

output

```
[
  { id: '3', firstName: 'Jen', lastName: 'Doe' },
  { id: '6', firstName: 'Stephanie', lastName: 'Joe' },
  { id: '1', firstName: 'Victoria', lastName: 'Doe' }
]
```